# polynomials with degree k

Tags: real-analysis

I just need to know whether I am right or not:If P be polynomial of degree k>0, with nonzero constant.Then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)=P(x/n)=P(0) \forall x\in (0,\infty)$ am I right?

Comment: Did you want to write this: $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}P(x/n)$? (In the original post, the econd limit is missing.)

Comment: yes thank you Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One needn't even require that the constant term be non-0 , nor restrict the value of x  to only positive reals.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  If $f$ is continuous at $a$, then $\lim_{x\to a} f(g(x))=f(\lim_{x\to a}g(x))$.